# Youtube Direct Lite or other solution

Tags: video, upload, youtube, hosting

We are currently building a website that shows videos. The videos will not be hosted on the website, but on our **own youtube channel**.

We want to build in a functionality where visitors of our website can log on to the website and have the option to upload a video. When a user uploads a video, we want that video to be directly uploaded on our **own youtube channel**, so we can review it first, before linking it to a video post on our website.

We have looked into youtube direct lite, but with youtube direct light the videos will be uploaded to the youtube channel of the visitors. We do not want this, we want the videos uploaded to the youtube channel of our website.

I hope my question is clear and hope anyone has a concrete solution to the above.

Many thanks,

PJ

Comment: what did you end up doing? would the non-lite version solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is against the YouTube terms of service -- you cannot have other users upload videos into your channel (this is why the YouTube Direct Lite project exists--to offer a similar end user experience without the real problem of making you liable for what others might put in your channel). If it's mandatory to have complete control over what's uploaded like you state, you'll have to either host the videos yourself or go with an OVP like Brightcove or Kaltura.